# Popup Alert in Google Chrome - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04

I am usign chrome in my Ubuntu 12.04 OS. From last two months for no reason I am getting an alert when a page completes loading. (Attaching the screenshots for the reference)

I'm not sure what is causing it, but I can certainly say that it is driving me nuts. Please help.

[image: Alert while browsing a site]

`Alert while opening a website`

[image: Alert while opening in a new tab]

`Alert while opening a new tab`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question. It was happening as an user was added to chrome, I am not sure how it got added. To solve this you need to do the following.

1) Go to Chrome -> Settings
2) Locate "User" section, make sure that there are no users, if any then delete them all.

This should then fix the above popup issue